# C++ Parse double argument as a string?

Tags: c++, string, function, arguments

I am wondering is there anyway to parse a double, int, or other numerical type argument as a string?

**For example**

The definition of the function:

```
 GetConfiguration(double mag, string &name, long &position, double &numAper)
```

The call up:

```
double myPag;
string myName;
long myPosition;
double myNumAper;
GetConfiguration(myPag, myName, myPosition, myNumAper);
```

In stead only pass the value to the parameter, can I know that the third parameter is something like "myPosition", something that the programmer actually typed?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want to know the name of the variable that was passed? If so, there is no built in mechanism to do that (because that information is often discarded as part of the compilation process), but there is macro trickery which can help. I'm not sure **why** you'd want to do that though...

Comment: If you can't do this in Python, the most reflective language on earth, why would you be able to do it in C++?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos It would lose with Lisp, I guess.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: ??? I've only touched the surface of Lisp, so I have NO clue what you're talking about.

Comment: I am trying to parse what is actually typed because I want to do something to prevent the scenario that the order of the input arguments is messed up.

Comment: @EvanTeran: Can I ask what is the macro trick you mentioned?

Comment: @NickXTsui That's nonsense. If you want to prevent that, make the function return a `struct`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Can you explain a little bit, or is there an example showing what you said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between a literal and a variable in this case is that a literal is an rvalue, and the variable *could be* an lvalue. That's why a literal argument won't match a non-const reference parameter.

However, **it doesn't make any sense** to test against that in this case. If you want a value of type `double`, you should allow everything that produces a double to be used. If you wan't "out" parameters, OTOH...

*Don't* use "out" parameters; use tuple return (`make_tuple`) and `tie` instead:

```
double myPag;
string myName;
long myPosition;
double myNumAper;
std::tie(myPag, myName, myPosition, myNumAper) = getConfiguration();
```

And if you are concerned about the proper order (as you mentioned in comments), just make the function return a `struct`:

```
struct Configuration {
    double myPag;
    string myName;
    long myPosition;
    double myNumAper;
};

auto configuration = getConfiguration();
do_stuff(configuration.myName);
```

If you are *still* not convinced and want more static safety, you need a strong type for every value that's semantically of different type (pseudo-C++):

```
using Pag = StrongTypedef<double, struct PagTag>;
using NumAper = StrongTypedef<double, struct NumAperTag>;

Pag myPag;
NumAper myNumAper;
```

That will ensure you won't be able to mismatch those.

#### However, nothing prevents you from making a mismatched assignment between two semantically identical types!

If you have two variables of type, say, `StrongTypedef<double, struct SomeTag>`, you will still be able to assign one to the other without problems. That kind of logic errors is pretty much impossible to convey in type system, and if you are concerned about that...

#### Well, just write unit tests.

I strongly believe in static typechecking, however it has its limits, and to test logic specific for the application you're making you will simply need unit tests to verify correct behaviour.

Comment: I don't see why returning a struct can prevent misorder happening? Do you mind explain a little?

Comment: Is that possible I plug in do_stuff(configuration.myPag), where as what I actually mean to write is do_stuff(configuration.myNumAper)?

Comment: @NickXTsui Yes, it is. The only way to prevent *that* would be a strong tagged type wrapping or replacing a double. Eh, I'll add a quick note, but that's quickly getting out of hand.